# Host HTML5 site on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: html, css, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to host my HTML5 site on Google Cloud Storage.

When I load the site locally, all the animations work. When I upload it to Google Cloud Storage and access it, my CSS animations don't work.

The CSS files are in `css/theme.css` in my storage bucket and the HTML file points to it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-elements.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-animate.css">
```

Comment: Can you access it by show source & click on the link's ?

Comment: Are there errors in the error console?

Comment: Now it reads the HTML page, but it reads it with simply HTML, it doesnt aply my CSS images or anything. What do i miss? I have made all files Public accasble.

Comment: If i click on the "public link" it presents the page perfect

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `Content-Type` metadata is set properly for your CSS files via the [Developer Console](https://cloud.google.com/console).

If not, you should manually edit the metadata to set the proper type, which is `text/css` for CSS files. If the type is neither not specified nor auto-detected at upload time, [Google Cloud Storage serves files as `binary/octet-stream`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#contenttype) which may prevent the browser from properly rendering it.

Alternatively, you can also specify the MIME type in HTML, e.g.,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">
```

to make sure that the browser handles it appropriately.